# Books & Lore Within Greyhawk

Tags: dnd-3.5e, lore, greyhawk

I'm currently running a 3.5e campaign set in Greyhawk and several of my players have become interested in the bookshops in town. In particular, the wizard wants to go down a forbidden knowledge path and find books on the occult.

I have no problem making this up as the DM, however if there are books that exist within Greyhawk I'd like to include those as well.

Perhaps among the regular titles such as 'insert legit Greyhawk books here' my character finds a book that I would create.

I've tried researching this on my own however finding books within a book is difficult. Search results usually return campaigns and players guides.

Is anyone familiar authors within Greyhawk or tomes of lore within the game setting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a well researched and sourced index of most books mentioned in Greyhawk lore here: https://web.archive.org/web/20170102205612/https://planejammer-the-infinity-arc.obsidianportal.com/wikis/tomes-and-grimoires

Many of the authors are all the "big names" you'd expect, famous mages like Otto, famous liches like Acererak...   The most famous occult book in Greyhawk is the Demonomicon of Igglwilv, if you want him to go for the big leagues.